# Reactjs - componentWillReceiveProps on button click - fails when button clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to React so quite likely there might be a better approach to what I'm trying to do.

I'm using React and Redux to pull HTML snippet from JSON file on click of the button and insert it in TemplateContent component.

The problem I'm having is that if I click the button twice in the row, i want the snippet to be inserted twice but since I'm preventing the loop in componentWillReceiveProps by checking that nextProps and this.props are not matching it does not work and I haven't been very lucky to finding my way around it so far.

This is my code...

```
class TemplateContentContainer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.fetchModule = this.fetchModule.bind(this)
        this.removeModule = this.removeModule.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.addedModule !== this.props.addedModule) // prevent infinite loop
        this.fetchModule(nextProps.addedModule)
    }

    fetchModule(id) {
        api
            .getModule(id)
            .then((module) => {
                this.props.dispatch(actions.receiveModule(module))
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('TemplateContainer Error: ' + err)
            })
    }

    removeModule(module) {
        this.dispatch(actions.removeModule(module))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TemplateContent
                templateModules={this.props.templateModules}
                removeModule={this.removeModule}
            />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    templateModules: state.receiveModuleById,
    addedModule: state.addModuleById, //returns id of added module - add me clicked
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    dispatch
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(TemplateContentContainer))
```

Let me know if you need any additional code or further explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Are those both module `ids` same which are fetched in a row?

Comment: yes, thats how the json file is being looked up

Comment: If they both have same ids, how can your logic works? And one more thing why do you want to load `html` content from `json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with multiple modules, i suggest you to not use it as the condition to re-render or not. you can always use a dummy props to change to your liking, as you are using redux that will not be a problem.

by dispatching action on click, `dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })` and having a reducer that matches that action, either adding ++int or any random thing will do.

then you will have to use it as the condition for the nextProps

`mapStateToProps = ({ counter }) => ({ ...counter })`

`nextProps.counter !== this.props.counter`

and with that i think you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

try this condition:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.templateModules !== this.props.templateModules)
    this.fetchModule(nextProps.addedModule)
}
```